# Magento find orphan products

Tags: php, magento

Is there an easy way I can pull/see a list of all products that are neither associated to a category or configurable product?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this SQL Query will help you.

```
 select
    type_id,sku
 from catalog_product_entity a
 left join catalog_category_product cp on cp.`product_id` = a.entity_id
 left join catalog_product_relation cpr on cpr.child_id = a.entity_id
 where 
       cp.product_id is null 
   and cpr.parent_id is null
   and a.type_id != 'configurable' -- per ben below
```

Comment: Need to exclude configurable ... `and a.type_id != 'configurable'`