# Echo a list of products that do not have a category assigned magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

What I want is a list of all the products that are not assigned to any category.

This has to be outside magento via a php script.

On stackoverflow I could not find an answer for this.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento find orphan products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567729/magento-find-orphan-products)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a mysql query that does what you're asking:

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku
FROM catalog_product_entity as cpe
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_product as ccp
on cpe.entity_id = ccp.product_id
WHERE category_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ [Magento list products that arent in a category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733372/magento-list-products-that-arent-in-a-category/19733875#19733875)

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_ids','');


foreach($collection as $p){
   echo $p->getName();
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Does this work? Isn't there a special filter method for categorys?

Comment: Unfortunatly the <br> is outputted more than 100 times, but the $p->getName is empty

Comment: @WouterdeVries, that's because the collection didn't load the "name" attribute. Just add this in between `getCollection()` and `->addAttributeToFilter` (preferably on its own line): `->addAttributeToSelect('name')`.